# Reduced homology of adjunction space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

would you please give a hint of how to begin with this exercise?

Let $\tilde{X}=X\cup e^{\lambda}$ is the adjuction of $\lambda-$cell, then the inclusion $i:X\to\tilde{X}$ induces isomorphism $$\tilde{H}_k(X) \xrightarrow{\;\; i_*{} \;\; } \tilde{H}_k(\tilde{X})$$ for $k\neq \lambda,\lambda-1$, and an exact sequence:
    $$0 \xrightarrow{\;\; {} \;\; }\tilde{H}_{\lambda}({X})\xrightarrow{\;\; i_*{} \;\; }\tilde{H}_{\lambda}(\tilde{X})\xrightarrow{\;\; {} \;\; } \mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\;\; {} \;\; }\tilde{H}_{\lambda-1}({X})\xrightarrow{\;\; i_*{} \;\; }\tilde{H}_{\lambda-1}(\tilde{X})\xrightarrow{\;\; {} \;\; }0$$

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C_k(X)$ denote the $k$-th cellular chain group of $X$. These make up
a complex $C_\bullet(X)$ whose homology is $H_k(X)$. The 
inclusion of$X$ into $Y=\tilde X$ induces an inclusion map, and so an exact
sequence
$$0\to C_\bullet(X)\to C_\bullet(Y)\to A\to 0$$
of chain complexes, where the complex $A$ just consists of a $\Bbb Z$
in dimension $\lambda$, corresponding to the adjoined cell. Taking
the long exact sequence of homology, gives the result, admittedly for
unreduced homology.

If you really want reduced homology, you need to modify your chain complexes
in one of the usual ways, say by tacking on a $\Bbb Z$ in dimension $-1$.